# Can I use dry mango leaves for puja?

Tags: puja

I don't have any local supermarket or market by me that sells fresh mango leaves for puja, can I order it online? it will be dry as that is all they offer online.

Comment: Dried leaves can't be used in puja. In this case instead of Mango, u can use Neem, Ashoka, Panchapallava (leaves from any 5 different trees) as to what you can arrange as per your settings.